# How to spread values evenly across partitions? ("Anti-partition")

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning

**EDIT [1]**: Modified sample data to accurately show the situation.
**EDIT [2]**: Added (test) code to show how it should work.

I have a (PySpark) dataframe that looks like this:

Sample data (shown in 2 columns):

```
ID  Type Other      ID  Type Other
--------------      --------------
101 A    1          105 A     1
101 A    2          105 A     2
101 B    1          105 B     1
102 A    1          105 A     4
102 A    2          106 A     1
103 A    1          106 A     2
103 A    2          201 B     1
103 B    1          201 A     1
104 A    1          202 B     1
104 A    2          203 B     1
104 A    3          203 B     2
```

I am already partitioning by ID.

How do I partition this data so that the **type** is also *spread* equally across multiple partitions?

So, if I just partition by ID, and I'm making 3 partitions, I could get this:

Partitions:

```
1        2        3
---      ---      ---
102 A *  101 A *  201 B *
104 A *  103 A *  202 B *
106 A *  105 A *  203 B *
         101 B *  201 A *
         103 B *
         105 B *
```

However, dealing with B is more computationally expensive than dealing with A, so I get a bottleneck on partition 3 that only has Type B.

Ideally, I'd like to partition the data like this:

```
1        2        3
---      ---      ---
101 A *  103 A *  105 A *
102 A *  104 A *  106 A *
201 B *  202 B *  203 B *
101 B *  103 B *  105 B *
201 A *
```

How do I do that?

The following code is an example of what I want to do:

```py
import random

import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark import Row
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

from test_common.test_base import PySparkTest

RANDOM = random.Random()


def spread_values_OVER_partitions(df_input: DataFrame, concentrate_col_name: str, spread_col_name: str) -> DataFrame:
    """This method SHOULD partition a dataframe so that the first column is partitioned normally, but the "spread_col_name" column is spread over all partitions.

    Args:
        df_input:               The dataframe to partitions
        concentrate_col_name:   The column (name) on which you should (normally) partition.
        spread_col_name:        The column (name) over which values should be SPREAD over the partitions.

    Returns:
        The repartitioned dataframe.
    """

    # THIS DOES NOT WORK!
    return df_input.repartition(3, concentrate_col_name, spread_col_name)


class PartitionSpreadTest(PySparkTest):

    def test_spread_partitioning(self):
        """Test how to spread a certain columns values *OVER* partitions, instead of concentrating them."""

        test_data_tuple = [(id, 'A', other) for id in range(101, 106) for other in range(1, RANDOM.randint(3, 4))]
        test_data_tuple.extend([(id, 'B', other) for id in [104] + list(range(201, 204)) for other in range(1, RANDOM.randint(4, 5))])

        test_data_dict = [{'id':    r[0],
                           'type':  r[1],
                           'other': r[2],
                           }
                          for r in test_data_tuple]

        df_test = self.spark.createDataFrame(Row(**x) for x in test_data_dict)
        num_part = 3

        df_test.groupby('id', 'type').agg(f.count('id')).orderBy('id', 'type').show(100, False)

        # This DOES NOT WORK!
        df_repartitioned = spread_values_OVER_partitions(df_test, concentrate_col_name='id', spread_col_name='type')

        partition_cols = ['id', 'type']
        print(f"Num partitions: [{num_part:3}]: \n")
        # print partitions
        (df_repartitioned.select(
            *partition_cols,
            f.spark_partition_id().alias('part_id'))
         .distinct()
         .groupBy(*partition_cols)
         .agg(f.collect_list('part_id').alias('part_ids'))
         .withColumn('num_parts', f.size('part_ids'))
         .orderBy('part_ids', *partition_cols).select(
            *partition_cols,
            'part_ids',
            'num_parts')
         .show(1000, False))
```

However, the above code outputs this:

```
+---+----+--------+---------+
|id |type|part_ids|num_parts|
+---+----+--------+---------+
|101|A   |[0]     |1        |
|104|A   |[0]     |1        |
|105|A   |[0]     |1        |
|202|B   |[0]     |1        |
|203|B   |[0]     |1        |
|104|B   |[1]     |1        |
|201|B   |[1]     |1        |
|102|A   |[2]     |1        |
|103|A   |[2]     |1        |
+---+----+--------+---------+
```

In this case,

- partition `[1]` *only* contains type B
- partition `[2]` *only* contains type A

which is the **opposite** of what I want.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if I need a window function on ('type', 'id') that assigns a different partition id ("row_number) per combination.  

I was hoping that there was an in-built or more elegant solution than that.

Answer (score 1):

If you need full flexibility, you could also

- convert Dataframe to RDD
- apply custom partitioner as shown below
- return back to Dataframe if necessary

#### Partitioner

Partitioner class is used to partition data based on keys. It accepts two parameters numPartitions and partitionFunc to initiate as the following code shows:

```py
def __init__(self, numPartitions, partitionFunc):
```

The first parameter defines the number of partitions while the second parameter defines the partition function.

[Source](https://kontext.tech/column/spark/299/data-partitioning-functions-in-spark-pyspark-explained)

Here is a pseudo code to show the basic idea:

#### Pseudo code

```py
# obviously this will put all your values in only partition 0 so thi function should get more complex
def myPartitionerFunc(key): 
    return 0 

# when defining the key-value paired RDD you could e.g. concatenate 'ID' and 'Type' value
dfToRDD = df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],x))
rdd = dfToRDD.partitionBy(3, myPartitionerFunc) 
dfPartitioned = spark.createDataFrame(rdd)
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Unfortunately, AFAIK, the round-trip between df <-> rdd will basically kill the Catalyst optimizer, which we heavily depend on.

Comment: Yes, this has a significant impact on the optimisation as you mentioned. I will make it more clearer in my answer that this approach should only be used when you really know what you are doing and that it highly depends on your use case. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: Mike, I'm also not convinced that there's a function that does what I need: something that combines "normal" partitioning with *spreading* another column's values over all partitions. Do you have any insight to this?

Comment: I haven't heard anything about it and am not aware of that kind of functionality...

Answer (score -1):

You can repartition by any number of columns. In your case you can do:

```
df.repartition("ID", "Type")
```

to repartition by (hash of) `ID` and `Type`. Docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition).

However note that if `Type` is dependent on `ID` (as your example suggests) it will not change much. This:

```
1        2        3
---      ---      ---
101 A *  104 A *  201 B *
102 A *  105 A *  202 B *
103 A *  106 A *  203 B *
```

is not really likely unless you [repartition by range](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartitionByRange) using ID alone. If you use standard hash partitioning, IDs (and therefore types) should be scattered randomly across partitions regardless of the keys you choose.

Comment: This is incorrect. This *concentrates* rows with similar "type" values in the *same* partition. That is exactly what I do NOT want.

Comment: No - it concentrates rows with same id AND type. Same type, but different ids will land in different partitions. Check it with a bit larger dataset and number of partitions.